# OpenSSL Certificate on Apache on Windows

Tags: apache, ssl

I have created the certificate via OpenSSL Apache 2.2 on Windows with self assigned and it's 2048 bit but when I check the certificate with OpenSSL s_client -connect hostname:443 it's displaying as 1024 bit and does not show any organization details. Does anyone know what's the default file path location it's reading it from?

Any quick help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You specify the path in your configuration file. Should be in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf